# Google Analytics page for getting my site's tracking code is stuck loading

Tags: google-analytics

I have just made a google analytics account.  When I get on and go to the tracking code tab my website is stuck loading.

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Restarting my computer
- Clearing my cache and cookies
- trying both chrome and Firefox browsers
- I removed my Kaspersky add-on from chrome
- going through the website in incognito tab
- logging out of all google accounts, then clearing cache, then logging back in.
- I checked that I have JavaScript enabled on chrome
- I tried using other sources of internet
- I deleted the only property I have and then recreated it
- I have waited 4 days

Comment: Is this working for you now?    I just tested for my existing GA property and the tracking code page loads just fine.   I also created a new test property and was able to get the tracking code snippet for it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to the antivirus software you have installed. To confirm whether that's the reason, disable the antivirus for a minute or so and run Google analytics. If the desired page loads up, white list the Google Analytics domain in the antivirus settings.

Comment: They said they disabled "Kaspersky" which sounds like their anti-virus.   It could also be an ad-blocker getting in the way.

Comment: Hello!  Thank you both for your help!  I both disabled my ad blocker and turned off Kaspersky entirely (previously I had only turned off the web add on for Kaspersky, not the program running.  The page now loads just fine!  I would upvote each of you if I had 15 reputation!  I will do so when I get enough reputation!  Thank you both!

Comment: Thanks to Stephen Ostermiller and user 34380! I had to both turn off my ad blocker (I was using NoAds) and I had to add google analytics to whitepages for Kaspersky. It took me a little effort to figure out how to do that. Here is the link which helped me figure out how to add a website to white pages in Kaspersky: https://support.igive.com/kb/a202/how-to-white-list-on-kaspersky.aspx

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DanielNimitz Thanks for the encouraging words. I too had faced the same problem. What I shared with you was my own personal experience. 